ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib_resume_builder_AIHawk'
I'm getting this error when I run my Python script:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib_resume_builder_AIHawk'
How can I fix this?
I tried installing the module using pip install lib_resume_builder_AIHawk, but still same.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We need to see your code, or a minimal representation of it, ideally as a [mre].


first insure that you are on your virtual environment:

if you are using windows :
<your virtual environment name>/Script/activate

if you are using ubuntu :
source <<your virtual environment name>>/bin/activate


list all the pip package installed on your virtual environment using pip
pip list

if you see the lib_resume_builder_AIHawk in your pip packages try reinstall it and install it again :


pip uninstall lib_resume_builder_AIHawk
pip install lib_resume_builder_AIHawk 

note :  check that you are using the correct python interpreter on your IDE
